# Reference not being passed when importing class on 32 bit machine

Tags: c#, vb.net, import, reference, 32bit-64bit

I have a Visual Studio solution that consists of several different classes that, when compiled, each produces a .dll file.  A majority of the classes are written in VB.Net, but some are written in C#.  One class, ClassA, is written in C# and has Sybase.Ado.Net4.AseClient in its References folder.  A separate class, ClassB, is written in VB.net, and it imports ClassA.  ClassB does not have Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient in its References folder.  Whenever this Visual Studio solution is opened on a 32-bit machine, the following error pops up for ClassB:

Error   2   Reference required to assembly 'Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient, Version=4.157.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95d94fac46c88e1e' containing the type 'Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection'. Add one to your project.

However, when this Visual Studio solution is opened on a 64-bit machine, no errors pop up.  We need to have this solution be able to compile successfully on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines, and we need to do it without adding Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection to ClassB's References.  Why is it that the error only pops up when using a 32-bit machine and not a 64-bit machine?  Since ClassA has Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection in its References, shouldn't ClassB get it by importing ClassA?

Comment: Can you open your project file in a text editor and provide the `HintPath` to that Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection reference?

Comment: There is no HintPath for Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection

Comment: Okay, I was looking in the .vbproj file of the entire visual studio solution and I didn't see a HintPath.  However, when I look at the ClassA.csproj file, I see this HintPath:

<HintPath>\\wblzbT02\BLZB\Executables\Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll</HintPath>

Comment: Is it possible that the 32 bit machine just doesn't have access to the UNC path where that Sybase DLL resides?  Might be that the 32 bit vs 64 bit issue is just coincidence...

Comment: But ClassA is able to reference the Sybase DLL, or are you suggesting that the UNC Path doesn't come into play when Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection is listed in the References folder for a class?